# How to Submit a html Form Submit Without Page Refresh using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I just watch this video and others video. All of them use ajax with 2 .php files but i already have file content.html that contain forms and content.php that submit form to database. how can i use ajax with my html file to submit form without reloading page.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOONJgPclwU

Comment: You can just use ajax to this. Here you can find more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/6357312

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a new question but still you can take help from this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "submit_form.php", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
 });
});
```

Comment: I already try this code but it doesn't work. It still reloading new page

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: Add `.click(function(e)` (added the `e`) and the add this in the first row in the `click`-callback: `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the jQuery library you can use code like

```
$("#theForm").ajaxSubmit({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'})
```

Please reference [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form) as it answers your question very well.